# IBM MFP8 - Unresponsive host error when adapter is called

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, adapter, mfp

I am getting below error when I try to obtain **access token** from the server using this code.

```
WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken()
    .then(
        function (accessToken) {
            console.log("accessToken ", accessToken);
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("error ", error);
});
```

**ERROR**

[See the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t9cb.png)

```
{
    "responseHeaders":{},
    "status":200,
    "responseText":"undefined",
    "errorCode":"UNRESPONSIVE_HOST",
    "errorMsg":"unresponsive host"
}
```

Usually when I get the access token, soft update is received but now soft update is not received because of this error.
Can anyone help?

Comment: OAuth protocol is not completely supported on browser simulator.If you try on emulator instead of browser simulator, do you face this issue?

Comment: what browser are you using? I had the same issue in Firefox and Edge when calling a API on a different domain than the one where the web app is served (and if you are developing, you may be in that exact scenario). Does it work on the device Simulator as Vivin suggests?

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 scenarios here.

1. MFP version of client and server is mismatched. Validated the version number of MFP and try again.
2. Application version number is not defined in MFP Console. So you can check the version number on MFP console.

let me know if that didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

your response status is 200. it means everything is fine. check if you don't have the required data in DB/Server what you are looking for.